# how do I use the constructor for Class.forName()

Tags: java, minecraft

The problem is that when I'm building a plugin for a Minecraft server. As that is my business, that packages always changes by different versions, like `net.minecraft.1_8R1`, but the class files inside never changes. So I'm trying to find the class by doing `Class.forName("net.minecraft." + getVersion() + "PacketPlayOutTitle")`. I have already made my own `getVersion()` method. But how do I use this PacketPlayOutTitle constructor, without importing it, so then my plugin will be compatible with different version of the server. Please, and thank you.

Comment: I edit my answer with example how to call constructor and method via reflection api without any need to import package.

Comment: I don't even understand how a package is containing the **version** of the application. Please slap these people for me, will ya?

Comment: Don't use package names to manage your application versions. This is a bad idea.

Comment: @Barett it isn't even OP. It's whoever publishes the Minecraft server does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection.

```
Class<?> packetClass = Class.forName("net.minecraft." + getVersion() + "PacketPlayOutTitle");
Object packet = packetClass.newInstance();
```

**EDIT**: Here is example without import. Method are invoked using reflection.

```
public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        //find class
        Class<?> fooClass = Class.forName("foo.Foo");

        //find constructor for given arguments
        Constructor<?> fooConstructor = fooClass.getConstructor(String.class, int.class);

        //call constructor
        Object foo = fooConstructor.newInstance("FooBar", 100);

        //find method
        Method getFooMethod = fooClass.getDeclaredMethod("getFoo");
        Method setFooMethod = fooClass.getDeclaredMethod("setFoo", String.class);
        Method getBarMethod = fooClass.getDeclaredMethod("getBar");
        Method setBarMethod = fooClass.getDeclaredMethod("setBar", int.class);

        //call method
        Object fooResult = getFooMethod.invoke(foo);
        System.out.println(fooResult);

        Object barResult = getBarMethod.invoke(foo);
        System.out.println(barResult);

        setFooMethod.invoke(foo, "BarFoo");
        setBarMethod.invoke(foo, 200);

        fooResult = getFooMethod.invoke(foo);
        System.out.println(fooResult);

        barResult = getBarMethod.invoke(foo);
        System.out.println(barResult);
    }
}

public class Foo {
    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    public Foo(String foo, int bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

This produce output:

```
FooBar
100
BarFoo
200
```

Comment: Where can I get Reflection?

Comment: Also how to I add arguments in the constructor?

Comment: The second line still requires an import of the PacketPlayOutTitle. I suppose casting will not be possible and it will only be possible to work on Object types

Comment: Reflections is a part of Java API. The new instance method takes any number of arguments, they just need to match the order from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much! Going to try it out!